# Unformatted Excel data import?

Tags: r, readxl, openxlsx, excel-import

I'm trying to read an Excel file with over 30 tabs of data.  The complication is that each tab actually has *2* tables in it.  There is a table at the top of the sheet, then a few blank rows, then a second table below with completely different column titles.

I'm aware of the `openxlsx` and `readxl` packages, but they seem to assume that the Excel data is formatted into tidy tables.

If I can get the raw data into R (perhaps in a text matrix...), I'm confident I can do the dirty work of parsing it into data frames.  Any advice?  Many thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! For code debugging please always ask with a [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1422451) example per the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [`r`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info) tag description. It's not clear what the problem is.

Comment: Perhaps with `tidyxl`? See also `jailbreakr`.

Comment: I was able to solve my problem by using `read_xlsx` from the `readxl` package, and setting the option `col_names = FALSE`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `XLConnect` package to access arbitrary region in Excel Worksheet. Then you can extract list of data frames.  Please see below:

**Simulation:**

```
library(XLConnect)

# simulate xlsx-file
df1 <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 0:9)
df2 <- data.frame(x = 1:20, y = 0:19)
wb <- loadWorkbook("temp.xlsx", create = TRUE )
createSheet(wb, "sh1")
writeWorksheet(wb, df1, "sh1", startRow = 1)
writeWorksheet(wb, df2, "sh1", startRow = 15)
lapply(2:30, function(x) cloneSheet(wb, "sh1", paste0("sh", x)))
saveWorkbook(wb)
```

[image: Excel]

**Extract Data**

```
# read.data
wb <- loadWorkbook("temp.xlsx")
df1s <- lapply(1:30, function(x) readWorksheet(wb, x, startRow = 1, endRow = 11))
df2s <- lapply(1:30, function(x) readWorksheet(wb, x, startRow = 15, endRow = 35))
df1s[[1]]
df2s[[2]]
```

**Output** `data.frame` #1 from the first sheet and `data.frame` #2 from the second one:

```
> df1s[[1]]
    x y
1   1 0
2   2 1
3   3 2
4   4 3
5   5 4
6   6 5
7   7 6
8   8 7
9   9 8
10 10 9
> df2s[[2]]
    x  y
1   1  0
2   2  1
3   3  2
4   4  3
5   5  4
6   6  5
7   7  6
8   8  7
9   9  8
10 10  9
11 11 10
12 12 11
13 13 12
14 14 13
15 15 14
16 16 15
17 17 16
18 18 17
19 19 18
20 20 19
```